# React: избавиться от многократной перерисовки дочерних компонент

Tags: reactjs, архитектура, redux, mobx, setstate

Есть такая структура

компонент `<MyPage />`,

который содержит компонент `<MyTable />`,

которая содержит Ant Design компонент `<Table />`

которому передаются данные по строкам, где каждая строка содержит компонент `<MyEditor />`

`MyPage` передаёт в `MyTable` массив строк текста `lines`

`MyTable` формирует массив данных для отображения в `Table`, которые содержат компоненты `MyEditor` которым передаются по одной строке из списка

```
  // подготовить данные для отображения в таблице
  const dataSource = props.lines.map((line, index) => ({
      key     : index,
      id      : index + 1,
      text    : <MyEditor
                  id            = {index} 
                  text          = {line}
                  onChange      = {handleChange} 
                />,
  }));

  // отрисовать компонент
  return (
    <Table
      pagination      = {false}
      columns         = {columns}
      dataSource      = {dataSource}
    />
  );
```

Внутри `MyEditor` строка разбивается на слова и из слов уже формируется набор  элементов.

Пользователь никак данные не может изменять, может только мышкой выбрать один из сформированных  элементов о чём информируется самый верхний компонент - `MyPage`, этот компонент спускает вниз эту информацию, чтобы компоненты `MyEditor` увидели скорректировали отрисовку (если требуется, но требуется редко).

Возникает проблема:

при каждом (!!!) таком выделении отрисовывается таблица, а значит и все компоненты `MyEditor` (несколько сотен), что заметно при работе (лаги)

Подскажите как правильно избежать этого?

P.S.

когда добавил в компонент `MyEditor` возможность вводить текст (поле Input), текст передаётся компоненту `MyPage`, но обратно не отдается, а просто сохраняется в состоянии, то тоже происходит отрисовка всех компонент `MyEditor`, что совершенно избыточно

Подскажите как скорректировать подход? Через Redux/Mobx писать сразу из `MyEditor` в общее хранилище и отслеживать его содержимое или как-то покрасивее можно?

Comment: Если у вас в `MyPage` лежит событие клики и далее передача вниз информации, то можно это событие повесить на сам элемент MyEditor и сохранить стейт в нем. Т.е. разделить хранилище. Redux тоже подойдет, особенно если родителю не интересно, что там ниже у дочек твоится и каждая дочка будет обладать собственным состоянием.

Comment: скорее дочернему не интересно, что делает родитель, клики ловятся внутри MyEditor
меня смущает перерисовка дочерних элементов потому что параметры же не изменились - грешу на Ant Design Table ведь она создает таблицу с новыми данными (хотя и на 99% идентичными старым)